# jemalloc shared library could not be preloaded to speed up memory allocations

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

Using Cassandra 3.4 in Ubuntu 14.04. JDK 8.
While Cassandra is starting I noticed the following warning in the warm-up:

> jemalloc shared library could not be preloaded to speed up memory
>   allocations

Any idea on how can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have a package `libjemalloc1` already installed?

Comment: @mmatloka nop, I didn't had it installed! Thanks mate! :D Put it as an answer so I can mark it ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to install the jemalloc package which under ubuntu is named `libjemalloc1`.

Comment: For completeness the general pattern is:

Comment: sudo apt update, then sudo apt upgrade, then sudo apt-get install libjemalloc1. I only add this because there was a time when I would read "install the jemalloc package" and think, okay, how do I do that?